# Macron accent not working

Tags: pdftex, accents, macron

I have the following `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{letter} `

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ipa}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Required for accented characters
\usepackage[margin=3.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{gfsdidot} 
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{microtype} % Improves typography
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}

\`{o}  \'{o}  \^{o}  \"{o}  \H{o}  \~{o}  \c{c}  \k{a}  \l{}  \={o}  \b{o}   \.{o}   \d{u}  \r{a}  \u{o}  \v{s} \t{oo}  \o

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

which after using pdflatex produces the following::

[image]

i.e. `\={o}` and  `\b{o}` aren't producing the bars above and below the `o` and `\v{s}` is doing nothing.

What's going on here?

Comment: Don't show snippets but a complete example that other can test.

Comment: I don't have `ipa.sty`, so if I throw out `\usepackage{ipa}` and complete the rest of the code to a full document I get the desired and expected output with macrons and bars. Does the issue go away for you if you don't load `ipa.sty`?

Comment: When I compile your code using the article class (and loading the `ipa` package) I get exactly the expected output, so the problem must be local to your set-up, for example, the class file that you are using. Please complete the code in your question to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) so that we have a chance of reproducing this.

Comment: Code updated. Problem persists....

Comment: Works fine for me, show your log-file.

Comment: There is no reason for loading `ipa`, because `tipa` supersedes it.

Comment: Getting rid of \usepackage{times} and using \usepackage{times} instead works. Closing this question.

Comment: i'm glad you got it to work, but `\usepackage{times}` = `\usepackage{times}`.  ???

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments (unclear what the solution was).